# Query MongoDB | Trying to query collection dimension of a db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to query a DB Mongo in order to obtain a list of all the collections and its related dimension.
I tried with the following query:

```
var dbs = db.getMongo().getDBNames();
for (adb of dbs) {
    var colls = db.getSiblingDB(adb).getCollectionNames({ type: "collection" })
    for (coll of colls) {
        var info = db.getSiblingDB(adb).getCollection(coll).stats(1024);
        if (info.ok) {
            print('Ns:' + info.ns + ' Storage Size:' + info.storageSize);
        }
    }
}
```

However my query extracts only some information because at a certain moment the following error message appears:

```
MongoServerError: not authorized on *DbName* to execute command { aggregate: "system.views", pipeline: [ { $collStats: { storageStats: { scale: 1 } } } ], cursor: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("xyz") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(123, 12), signature: { hash: BinData(0, xyz), keyId: xyz} }, $db: "*DbName*" }
```

I used xyz in order to hide some information in the error message.

Does anyone could help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages is quite clear, you lack required privileges. However, you try to run `stats()` on a view, which is pointless anyway.

```
db.getSiblingDB(adb).getCollectionNames({ type: "collection" })
```

does not work, use

```
db.getSiblingDB(adb).getCollectionInfos().filter(x => x.type == 'collection').map(x => x.name)
```

Comment: Using `db.getSiblingDB(adb).getCollectionInfos().filter(x => x.type == 'collection').map(x => x.name)` gives me the same result of my code `db.getSiblingDB(adb).getCollectionNames({ type: "collection" })`. My query starts providing some partial results, but after about 200 lines it stops and the same previous error message appears. I know that I have not some required priviliges, but I don't understand which views and/or collections gave me this problem and, as a consequence, I don't know which filter I need to add to my query in order to avoid it.

Comment: Strange, for me `db.getCollectionNames({ type: "collection" })` returns all collections and this filter is [not documented](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/current/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/) either. Apart from that, error says `aggregate: "system.views"`, so looks like it tries to run `db.stats()` on a view rather than on a collection. Use `print(coll)` before you run `stats()`, then it shows the collection name.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. My query stops its execution when it finds the object called "system.views". It seems to be a system collection. Do you know how I can write my query in order to avoid this error? Do I have to put a filter that allows me to "jump" this type of objects during the query execution?

Comment: Are you sure? For me the second command is working fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't work. This is the definitive query I ran: `var dbs = db.getMongo().getDBNames();
 
for (adb of dbs) {
    var colls = db.getSiblingDB(adb).getCollectionInfos().filter(x => x.type == 'collection').map(x => x.name)
 
    for (coll of colls) {
        print(coll)
        var info = db.getSiblingDB(adb).getCollection(coll).stats(1024);
        if (info.ok) {
            print('Ns:' + info.ns + ' Storage Size:' + info.storageSize);
        }
    }
}`. The query execution stops when it finds "system.views".

Comment: I still have no idea why it doesn't work but you can put it in a `try {...} catch (err) {}` block. Do you run it with root privileges?

Comment: 'system.veiws' is a system collection that contains information about all of the views in the database.  The built-in read/write roles _do not_ provide permissions for system collections.  Options: 1) filter the list of names to skip any that start with /system/, 2) grant your user a role with explicit rights for system collections, 3) use try/catch to return a default size for collections you can't read.

Comment: I solved the problem with the following query: `db.getCollectionInfos().forEach(function(collectionInfo) {
    var collectionName = collectionInfo.name;
    var isSystemCollection = collectionName.startsWith('system.');
    var isView = collectionInfo.type === 'view';
    
    if (!isSystemCollection && !isView) {
        var stats = db.getCollection(collectionName).stats();
        var size = stats.size;
        print(collectionName + "; " + size);
    }
});`. Thank you all for your support.